# Internal(expanded) version of enum class

Tags: java, enums

This is an example took form http://www.javatpoint.com/enum-in-java

```
enum Season{  
    WINTER(10), SUMMER(20); 

    private int value;

    Season(int value) {  
        this.value=value;
    }
}
```

Author was claiming that this was the Internal code generated by the compiler for the above example of enum type

```
final class Season extends Enum {  
    public static Season[] values() {  
        return (Season[])$VALUES.clone();  
    }

    public static Season valueOf(String s) {  
        return (Season)Enum.valueOf(Season, s);  
    }

    private Season(String s, int i, int j) {  
        super(s, i);  
        value = j;  
    }

    public static final Season WINTER;  
    public static final Season SUMMER;  
    private int value;  
    private static final Season $VALUES[];

    static {  
        WINTER = new Season("WINTER", 0, 10);  
        SUMMER = new Season("SUMMER", 1, 20);  
        $VALUES = new Season[] {  
            WINTER, SUMMER  
        };  
    }  
}
```

Could any please tell which tool help in viewing the internal(exapnded) version of enum

Comment: probably a class file viewer

Comment: I tried jd-gui but it did not show the expanded version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jad ( http://varaneckas.com/jad/ ) here is the output I got:

```
// Decompiled by Jad v1.5.8g. Copyright 2001 Pavel Kouznetsov.
// Jad home page: http://www.kpdus.com/jad.html
// Decompiler options: packimports(3) 
// Source File Name:   Season.java


final class Season extends Enum
{

    public static Season[] values()
    {
        return (Season[])$VALUES.clone();
    }

    public static Season valueOf(String s)
    {
        return (Season)Enum.valueOf(Season, s);
    }

    private Season(String s, int i, int j)
    {
        super(s, i);
        value = j;
    }

    public static final Season WINTER;
    public static final Season SUMMER;
    private int value;
    private static final Season $VALUES[];

    static 
    {
        WINTER = new Season("WINTER", 0, 10);
        SUMMER = new Season("SUMMER", 1, 20);
        $VALUES = (new Season[] {
            WINTER, SUMMER
        });
    }
}
```